# How to Install multiple Ubuntu Operating Systems with Shared Boot Partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

I have a computer (laptop) and a hard disk to which I have already created partitions for my Operating Systems and a Boot partition, which has Grub2 and the /boot files.

What is the proper way to install multiple Ubuntu Operating Systems and update GRUB2 to allow me to select which OS to boot?
(in my case, the Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop and a minimal server install)

Comment: good question.. thumbs up..

Answer (score 2):

As you described you have created separate partition, it is fairly possible to install multiple **Ubuntu** operating systems and use  which ever you want.

While installing **Ubuntu** just chose the last option **Do something else** and select the partition in which you want to install **Ubuntu**. Best thing is that you can chose same **Swap** partition for all Ubuntu installation.

After finishing installation you may need to use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) a very good package to fix/built **Grub** related issues.

Hope you can understand from this short description.

Comment: I actually managed to boot the server install by using `update-grub` and then using grub-customizer to fix it by copy-pasting the partition GUID into place. However, this requires a ppa and lot's of manual tweaking, so it is probably not the _right_ way to do it.

Comment: pretty cool.. good to know other way also..

Comment: It really should work just by running `update-grub`, but the entries created were wrong. I'm leaving this question in the hope that the right way to do this is found / documented.